# Unable to cat the contents of a directory when there are spaces in the file names

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use `ls | xargs cat >> files.txt` to write out all of the filenames within a directory to my text file. Unfortunately, this doesn't work when there are spaces in the filename due to the way xargs is handled. Is there a way to force xargs to stop considering spaces different files?

For example, let's say these are the contents of my directory:

file1 with spaces.txt

file2 with spaces.txt

Running `ls | xargs cat >> files.txt` would get an error like:

`cat: file1: No such file or directory`

`cat: with: No such file or directory`

`cat: spaces: No such file or directory`

`cat: file2: No such file or directory`

`cat: with: No such file or directory`

`cat: spaces: No such file or directory`

How do I force xargs to read the names correctly, i.e. "file1 with spaces.txt"?

Comment: It's both about `xargs` and about `ls`. Do not use `ls`. But why not `cat * >> files.txt`?

Comment: Ok, what should I use instead?

Comment: @KamilCuk : Your solution would store the **contents** of the files into `files.txt`. The OP obviously wants the file names.

Comment: @yoursweater : How about `ls >> files.txt`? Of course this would cause trouble if you have file names containing a newline character, but in this case, you need to specify in your question what files.txt should contain. Of course, `files.txt` will also be in the list, but I guess this is what you want to have anyway.

Answer (score 3):

[Do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

From man xargs:

> xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected with double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines

So, not only it interprets blanks, they can also be protected with quotes and backslashes, which, well, depending on your input may cause more confusion. Use `xargs -t` to debug `xargs`. Specifying `-d` or `-0` option with `xargs` allows xargs to act properly.

While you could do one of:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type f | xargs -d '\n' cat > files.txt
# or better, handle newline in filenames
find . -mindepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat > files.txt
# or evan better, just `find`
find . -mindepth 1 -type f -exec cat {} + > files.txt
```

assuming there are only filenames, just use glob:

```
cat * >> files.txt
cat *.txt >> files.txt
```

Note that writing and reading from the same file at the same time will most probably result in an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that that `find` with the `-print` flag would work after looking at the `find` manual:

`find *.txt -print | cat >> files.txt`

Source where I found the information: https://math2001.github.io/article/bashs-find-command/

Comment: Just wondering: what is wrong with just `cat *.txt > files.txt`?

Comment: Then if you just want the list of files matching `*.txt` into `files.txt`, then do `printf '%s\n' *.txt >files.txt`

Comment: `-print` is the default action if you don't use any, equivalent to `find *.txt | ...`

Comment: Keep out: `ls` and `find` do different things: `ls` only checks the current directory, while `find` goes through the subdirectories as well. This is the exact reason why I put `-maxdepth 1` as an extra parameter in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This one has it all:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -exec cat {} \;

maxdepth 1    : makes sure you only verify that one directory (./)
-name "*.txt" : I suppose you only want textfiles
-exec cat {}  : execute "cat <search result>", search result being represented as {}
\;            : standard way to end a "find ... -exec ..."
```